# Write own exception for extra information, even though a specialized exception already exists?

Tags: c#, exception

My method checks if all given parameters have a valid format and if not, it should throw an exception.

There is already a exception type for this kind of exception: `System.FormatException` with the summary:

> The exception that is thrown when the format of an argument is invalid, or when a composite format string is not well formed.

The method takes multiple parameters and each parameter could be the reason for this exception.

I want to tell the user which parameter is invalid, but `System.FormatException` doesn't have a property for this information.

So what should I do:

- Add the information to the message property of the `System.FormatException` and if needed check with `.Contains("bla")` which parameter caused the exception
- Throw an `System.ArgumentException` with the `ParamName` set to the parameter name and `InnerException` set to a new instance of `System.FormatException`
- Write own `ArgumentFormatException` class with a `ParamName` property

Comment: This question is likely to be a source for opinionated answers, but personally, I think the second option (or something like it) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use your second option, or a derivative of it, from the stance that:

The outer exception thrown is the *most recent* exception it encountered. When the user queries the exception, they can surmise the exact problem. Since the formatting is what *caused* the `ArgumentException`, you could specify a custom message for it instead of setting an `InnerException` value. It has a constructor that takes a message and a parameter, I would use that.

If I were designing this API, I would not set `InnerException` at all, and just provide a custom message for `ArgumentException` indicating that the parameter had an invalid format.